# C# method argument of type "Type" is not valid despite of the fact that it's exactly expecting a type

Tags: c#, types

I have the following method that takes an argument of type "Type":

```
public List<Entity> FindEntityByClass(string layer, Type type)
        {
            return layerDict[layer].Where(entity => entity.GetType() == type).ToList();
        }
```

Here I call it:
`SceneManager.currentScenes[0].FindEntityByClass("main", Entity1).Destroy();`
The error is on this line: "Entity1 is a type, which is not valid in the given context"
However, the error confirms that Entity1 is a type, which makes not sense knowing that FindEntityByClass expects a type as second argument.

Comment: `Entity1` itself **is not** an instance of type `Type`. Types in C# are not really first class citizens. Did you mean to call it with `typeof(Entity1)`? It is a special operator that turns type into `Type` instance. That being said I encourage you to turn the function into generic `FindEntityByClass<T>(string layer)` and use `entity is T` test. Unless there's a reason to not know the Type argument beforehand?

Comment: Use typeof(Entity1) instead.

Answer (score 2):

We can simply use a generic like this instead of trying to pass a type as an argument:

```
public List<Entity> FindEntityByClass<T>(string layer)
        {
            return layerDict[layer].Where(entity => entity is T).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: That's just `OfType<T>()` with extra steps.